# Making an exception for SSLVerifyClient require

Tags: ssl, apache2

I have apache2 httpd version 2.2.9 listening on port 443 with SSLEngine on. All URLs have `SSLVerifyClient require` and this works fine.

I want to make an exception for a specific URL (`/ca.crt`) so that my clients can download the certificate of the CA that the certificates we issue them are signed with. I try the following:

```
SSLVerifyClient require

Alias /ca.crt /my/ssl/certs/ca.crt
<Location /ca.crt>
  SSLVerifyClient none
</Location>
```

My problem is that Apache only seems to want to increase the strength of the SSL client certificate requirement. If I flip the two requirements around, it works as specified. As it is configured above, Apache effectively ignores the `SSLVerifyClient none` directive.

What's going on? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that the answer to this question is in the documentation (as it usually is!)

> In per-server context [the SSLVerifyClient directive] applies to
>   the client authentication process used
>   in the standard SSL handshake when a
>   connection is established.

[See Apache Docs - SSLVerifyClient](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslverifyclient)

Basically the first `SSLVerifyClient` directive was in the per-server context. I made an explicit `<Directory>` declaration for the root directory and put the `SSLClientVerify require` directive in there. This did the trick.